# downloading file to ipad

Tags: ipad, asp-classic

I have a results set displayed on a web form.  One of the options available to the user is to download the results as a .xls spreadsheet.  I am trying to update this classic asp code so that the downloads page can be saved to an iPad and the user can then view it in something like QuickOffice if they so wish.

The code so far is:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = true
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=results.xls"
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
```

The page then goes and runs and after everything has been generated:

```
response.flush()
response.clear()
```

The problem is that rather than allowing the contents to be saved, via the dialogue, the contents are displayed in the browser with the original .asp page header, how do I stop this?

Edit:

I have been trying this method:

```
Response.Buffer = true
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ConversionResult.xls;"

'and i send the file using the stream as
Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
adoStream.Open() 
adoStream.Type = 1 
adoStream.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath("xls/streamtest.xlsx")) 
Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read() 
adoStream.Close 
Set adoStream = Nothing
response.Flush
response.end
```

The user has permission on the file structure but nothing happens the browser just spins.  Firstly let me defend myself in some way... I do not own an iPad and have only spent a short time 'playing' with the one that is available to me.  I too have not seen a 'save as' or similar dialogue box when trying to download files and am really in the process of reading about the iPad's capabilities.

There is a safari download manager plugin but I am trying to determine if this is only available to jail broken ipads as obviously this is not an option for our normal customers.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you confident the iPad browser allows _downloading_ or _saving_? At least I haven't seen a file "Browse" dialog on my iPod yet...

Comment: Yes you can, or I have been informed that you can but it was being done slightly differently!  I'm wondering what is wrong with this method?!

Comment: Do you output your text in binary? `response.binaryWrite`?

Comment: Yes the output is Binary write.

Comment: similar question posted on [Clarification on what can be exported to excel on ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692484/clarification-on-what-can-be-exported-to-excel-on-ipad/10789370#10789370) with a working solution already

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to stream it to a temporary file using FSO then link to it. 
That way Safari (ipad) should give the option to save.